Error installing Mongodb 4.4 on Raspberry pi 4B 8Gb
I have 2 Raspberry pi 4B of 8 Gb, same micro SD card (make, model and capacity), same processor, same updated OS, they are almost a clone except for the installed applications, which are not unusual either.
In one of them I have installed Mongodb 4.4 without any problem following the instructions on the net and it is working. In the other there is no way, an "illegal instruction" appears when I try to run the engine and it does not start.
These are the characteristics of the 2 RPi:
enter image description here
I've tried with lower versions, deleted everything and reinstalled the whole package, but it doesn't work. In fact, it doesn't even generate the Mongo log so I can see what could happen, I've even given that folder read/write rights for anyone in case there was a permissions problem.
I've also adjusted the memory allocated to Mongo, the swap and everything I've seen on the net.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Does anyone have a solution? It also fails in Docker.

'Illegal instruction' usually means the mongod needs AVX but the CPU doesn't have that extension.

If you would like to run a newer version of MongoDB, please see these binaries which I publish on github: https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries. Indeed, you have a binary which has not been compiled for the pi platform if you are seeing an illegal instruction error.
